# jquery dialogs in quirks mode doesn't set height correctly

Tags: jquery, dialog, quirks-mode

I am writing a jquery based widget that will go on another company's website. When I try to set the height of the dialog via $('#dialog').height(450), it sets the dialog to be much shorter. I'm able to get it about 450px high by using 300 (I know, makes no sense). I've determine that the bug happens in IE8 in quirks mode. Yes, I know jquery doesn't support quirks mode. I can't change the doctype, since it's not my website.

Even though what I did worked, I need to understand why. Is there a definitive guide to how jquery works in quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied padding to the dialog?

The box model is rendered differently if you're using quirks mode.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Padding wouldn't explain why setting the height to anything greate than 380px makes the dialog shorter. I've tested this, and the following line of code makes the dialog 1 pixel high: var dialogHeight = 381; $('#WebIQDialog').dialog( "option", "height", dialogHeight);

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid quirks mode, if possible. However, if that isn't an option, I've had success doing this: (I'm assuming that you're using jQueryUI)

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").css("height", "450px");
```

Which resizes the outer CSS of the jQueryUI dialog.

Comment: no, it set the dialog to be about 50px high. For some reason, whenever I try to set the height of the dialog to any higher than 380px, it becomes much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the this style rule and adjust the heigth to your requirements:

```
.ui-dialog { height:700px !important; }
```

Open the dialog with

```
dialog.dialog("open");
```

and set the heigth of the dialog to auto in order to adjust the inner content:

```
dialog.css("height", "auto");
```